# Responsive 4 section layout

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design

I have a site that has a main section, a bottom bar that contains buttons and then two information sections. When the device is held in landscape mode I want the main section to be on the left, the two extra sections to be stacked vertically on the right and the bottom bar to be on the bottom. Like so:
[image: Horizontal]

When the device is held portrait, I want the main section to be in the middle, the two extra sections to be stacked vertically above it and for the bottom bar to be on the bottom. Like so:
[image: Vertical]

In each one, the main section needs to resize to be as big as it can (the pictures are slightly misleading). I've been able to achieve each one on its own using tables, however, I want to avoid having to have two copies of everything and just hiding one or another when the screen is rotated.

Is there a good way to make this work? I'm already using jQuery so I'm not against using that, but ideally, if I could do it in just pure CSS then that would be awesome.

P.S. It's a web app so it needs to fill the entire screen without any scrollbars.

Comment: It would be hard to do with css. If these 2 extra section were on left - it would be much easier. I don't know, do you use any css libraries, but [W3.CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/w3css) contains such features and can do that, although, it gives the webpage its own look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this using CSS, no problem.

Define a resolution from which your second layout kicks in, and using a media query for that resolution float your main area left and the two information sections right. Use a % width for all of them.

Even simpler would be to use [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) and define these layouts using their grid.

Comment: Sounds good. I'm not able to whip this up right now, but I'll give it a shot as soon as I can. By the way, how do I use a media query to tell what orientation the screen is in?

Comment: This sounds like a tricky path, that's why I suggested you draw the line based on horizontal real-estate, and not on orientation. Anyway you can use a media query such as:

@media all and (orientation: portrait) { ... }

As explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#orientation).

Let me know if whether managed to implement the above solution!

Comment: I ended up using flexbox, but I marked you answer as correct as it also worked, just with a decent bit more faffing.

Comment: Awesome, @Bottersnike! Thanks. Indeed, CSS positioning is a bit of an art-form, and flexbox promises to make things simpler for everyone. Glad you cracked the issue! :)